# Опыт участия в PHP (и других) Opensource проектах

Tags: php, github, symfony, opensource

Уважаемое сообщество, хотел бы узнать у вас как именно вы принимаете (если принимаете) участия в OpenSource?

Я хочу пояснить вопрос. Однажды один из ресурсов, который был использован одним  из бандлов в Symfony, изменил API. Естественно что код стал работать не корректно и на моем ресурсе отвалилась авторизация.

Я порылся, нашел где проблема. Переопределил нужный сервис, внес свои правки. Ну и само собой решил что неплохо было бы предложить pull request вендору с правками данного сервиса.

Для этого мне пришлось стянуть в отельный проект бандл, туда сделать правки ну и отправить собственно тот самый запрос на изменение.

Вот и возникает вопрос. Работать таким образом с библиотеками совершенно не реально ибо библиотеки отдельно, а ваш проект отдельно (на самом деле реально, если работать через тесты) и вот в аккурат выливается вопрос `кто то каким то образом имеет готовый рецепт работы со сторонними библиотеками одновременно работая со своим проектом ? Чтоб можно было бы не отходя от кассы комитить в нужные места нужные изменения ?`  Да и вообще, поделитесь пожалуйста опытом в этом направлении. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю, что вопрос специфичен для php. Мы, когда работаем в Unity3d тоже разные библиотеки/плагины используем. Думаю, в целом везде +- одинаково.

Думаю, в штуках вроде node.js/php и можно было бы настроить локальные зависимости так, чтоб можно было удобно пулл реквесты посылать, но, в любому случае, вам перед этим придётся форкать оригинальный репозиторий.

Так что, механизм в целом похож:

1. Вы используете модуль/библиотеку.
2. Если всё хорошо, то всё хорошо (:
3. Если что-то сломалось

   1. Форкаете оригинальный модуль/библиотеку.
   2. Правите там всё, что надо.
   3. Пушите в свой форк и отправляете пул реквест.
   4. Собираете модуль/библиотеку (если надо) и подключаете к проекту как локальную зависимость.
   5. Если ваш пулреквест примут, то можете снова переключиться на удалённый репозиторий.

В случае с php, я не знаю, что там сейчас модно. composer? Там вроде есть возможность подключать локальные пакеты. Так что, часть зависимостей у вас будет по старинке из удалённых реп, а часть зависимостей на локальные пакеты.

Comment: Ну по сути да, вы описали ровно тот же механизм. Вот меня как раз и смутило то, что приходится форкать и править библиотеку, которая "стоит отдельно" не в контексте приложения. Я понимаю что работоспособность можно (и главное нужно) описывать тестами, однако, согласитесь, ощущение неудобства существует. 

А вот по поводу замечания перевести требуемые зависимости на локальные пакеты, которые предварительно форкнул, весьма дельно звучит. Были мысли по этому поводу но как то не оформились в действия. Все же чтоб не "придумывать" способы хотел бы узнать как делают те, кто вовлечен в opensource.

Comment: Ну и да, конечно вопрос не специфичен для PHP, я лишь привел его в пример, т.к. столкнулся именно с этим.

Answer (score 0):

Долго ли коротко ли, а все дело сводилось к тому что либо когда я читал документацию к GIT я ее плохо читал, либо когда я ее читал, этой возможности  не было (в чем я сомневаюсь конечно).

Однако отвечая  на свой же вопрос было обнаружено такое полезное действо как [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8)
что дает нам возможность в рамках своего проекта определять в папке автономный подмодуль, который собственно говоря и можно редактировать в рамках проекта. Очередная прекрасная возможность git .

Comment: На самом деле - Вам не нужны сабмодули. Достаточно не делать 'composer update' каждый раз когда Вам захочется.

Answer (score 0):

Опишу свое мнение по этому вопросу.

*Что касается поломанного проекта*

Composer настолько крутой инструмент, что при каждой установке/обновлении зависимостей создает/обновляет [`composer.lock`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#lock-file) файл.

Так вот, вся магия в нем - для того, чтобы ничего не сломать - достаточно просто не игнорировать его (`.gitignore`) и не делать без надобности `composer update`.

А как на счет новых зависимостей в уже существующий проект? - [`composer require`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require):

> After adding/changing the requirements, the modified requirements will be installed or updated.

Таким образом, `composer.lock`, `composer install`, `composer require` - Ваши друзья в превентивной борьбе с поломанными зависимостями и, как следствие, проектом.

---

*Что касается opensource contributing*

Обычно это происходит так:

- делаем fork нужного проекта
- от master (обычно это master) branch'а откалываем свою ветку
- в новой ветке делаем изменения
- git push изменений в репозиторий
- делаем pull request в репозиторий vendor'a
- ждем merge/decline

[Здесь](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/GitHub-Contributing-to-a-Project) все отлично описано в контексте github

---

Что касается `git submodule` - это не то чтобы сильно популярный функционал. Попытка git'a сделать альтернативу composer'y, которая кстати не лишена [проблем](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8).

Comment: Я боюсь вы не поняли в чем мои сомнения, а она именно в том что вы и описали. Если вы делаете форк условной библиотеки в которой делаете нужные вам изменения в какой именно момент вы планируете использовать библиотеку в своём проекте?  После мерджа изменений ? Или вы предлагаете делать копию изменённой в папку с вендорами после каждого изменения ?

Comment: @zalex я просто сделаею extends нужно класса и поправлю что нужно)